# How do I prevent security risks using Spring JPA save?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Assuming, in my system a user wants to change his password. He sends a `PUT` request which then calls `UserRepository.save()`. If he hacks into the request, he might set `[user].admin_rights=1` or similar.

Now I could probably add `@Column( updatable=false )` to the respective field:

```
@Entity public class User {
    @Column(updatable=false) private Boolean admin_rights;
    // ....
```

, but an admin might require to update this field one day!

Do I need to write a custom query for this, specifying which columns to update? Or is there a way to solve this permission problem within the `User` entity?

Comment: Check out spring security, particularly maybe using a `@PreAuthorize` intercept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the responsibility of the application to enforce permissions like this. On your endpoint, you should verify that the incoming entity is valid before attempting to save it. In this case, "valid" means that the user is not attempting to elevate their rights inappropriately. The application should never blindly trust data that is sent from the users.